# python list comprehension to create repeated value from the list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create

```
[ x 
 for x in [1,2,3] 
     for y in [3,1,4] ]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

but what I want is to create

- 1 3 times
- 2 1 times
- 3 4 times

**Expected Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Is it possible to do this in list comprehension ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up your numbers with their counts:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
counts = [3, 1, 4]
output = [n for n, c in zip(numbers, counts) for _ in range(c)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, with `zip`:

```
>>> [item for x,y in zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4]) for item in [x]*y]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm you could also use `np.repeat` if you fine with an array as a results

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat([1, 2, 3] ,[3, 1, 4])
```